# Display data as xml page inside of a jsp page(cannot be seperate .xml file) and style with xslt

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt, stylesheet

For my project i have to display data as an xml file inside of a jsp page. 
So far i have done this inside <%  %> and it prints the values just fine but does not appear to be referencing the stylesheet :

```
            out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\">");
            out.println("<?xml-stylesheet href=\"change.xsl\" type=\"text/xsl\" ?>");
            out.println("       <countryList>");
            out.println("           <name>" + name + "</name>");
            out.println("           <description>" + result2.get(i++) + "</description>" );
            out.println("           <culture>" + result2.get(i++) + "</culture>");
            out.println("       </countryList>");
```

And this is my seperate xslt stylesheet which appears not to be working :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
    <xsl:template match="countryList">     
        <table border="1">    
            <tr bgcolor="#669999">               
                <th>Name</th>             
                <th>Description</th>             
                <th>Culture</th>    
            </tr>            
            <xsl:for-each select="countryList">      
                <tr>     
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>     
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="culture"/></td>                    
                </tr>    
            </xsl:for-each>  
        </table><br/>             
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Use a `Transformer` to apply the XSLT transformation in your code. I am not familiar with JSP, so perhaps it has its own tag set to apply an XSLT transformation. Also note that your code creating the XML creates a root element named `CountryList` with `name`, `description` and `culture` child elements while your XSLT matches on `CountryList` but then with the `for-each select="CountryList"` tries to process child `CountryList` elements of the matched `CountryList`, these child elements don't exist in your sample at all. And don't try to construct XML with string concatenation, that can fail.

Comment: If you must rely on the client to perform the transformation then, (1) ensure that the value of the `content-type` header is correct.  Probably it should be `application/xml`, which is not the default for JSP. (2) Ensure that the stylesheet URI, as resolved against the context's base URL, in fact references the desired stylesheet.